# Css files not loading properly in sharepoint server 2019, only in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-server, css, html, content-editor-web-part, bug

I have some custom html e js files that i am using in PDPs,  (pages) of sharepoint, but the css its not being loaded.

I importing the files like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../SiteAssets/js/SlickGrid/Css/slick.grid.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../SiteAssets/js/SlickGrid/Css/slick.pager.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../SiteAssets/js/SlickGrid/css/jquery-ui.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../SiteAssets/js/SlickGrid/Css/examples.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../SiteAssets/js/SlickGrid/Css/slick.columnpicker.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../SiteAssets/js/PDP/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css" href="../SiteAssets/Js/Bootstrap/startbootstrap/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
```

The css files are loaded but not "executed". However when a put some css code from a external address (cdn) the style works properly.

I used this files in sharepoint online and always works fine. What am my missing when doing this in sharepoint server 2019?

Answer (score 2):

Are the files checked in?

Is the path valid? What happens if you change

```
../SiteAssets/js
```

to an absolute path:

```
http://yourserver/sites/yoursite/SiteAssets/js....restOfYouPath....
```

Comment: Still the same. I can see in console that the css are loaded to the page, but for some reason it is like the files is not executing/reading the css file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a known issue in SharePoint 2019, you may need to wait for a hotfix to fix this issue.

[Common issue: SP2019 – Items in document libraries are downloaded with mime-type application/octet-stream rather than the accurate one](https://blog.stefan-gossner.com/2018/11/30/common-issue-sp2019-items-in-document-libraries-are-downloaded-with-mime-type-application-octet-stream-rather-than-the-accurate-one/)

Answer (score 0):

Known issue but a good explanation and a workaround is here:

[workaround for CSS style fix on Sharepoint 2019](https://joemcshea.intellipointsolutions.com/why-dont-my-css-files-work-on-sharepoint-2019/)

Comment: Please don’t post link-only answers as links often break now and then.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/119753)